# Laravel find_in_set and concat not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I cant join tables with find_in_set and concat on my join condition.
This is the query i want

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(sizes.name),`products`.`name`, `products`.`image`,
 `products`.`id`, `products`.`image_second`, `products`.`description`,
 `products`.`min_order`, `size_categories`.`size_id` from `products` 
inner join `subcategories` on `products`.`subcategories_id` = `subcategories`.`id` 
inner join `size_categories` on `subcategories`.`categories_id` = `size_categories`.`categories_id` 
join sizes on (FIND_IN_SET(concat('\'',sizes.id,'\''),size_categories.size_id)>0) where `products`.`id` = '7'
```

In laravel, what i could make is

```
$productDetails = DB::table('products')
        ->join('subcategories', 'products.subcategories_id', '=', 'subcategories.id')
        ->join('size_categories', 'subcategories.categories_id', '=', 'size_categories.categories_id')
        ->join('sizes',function($join){
            $join->on(DB::raw("find_in_set(sizes.id, size_categories.size_id)"));
         })
        ->where('products.id', $request->id)
        ->select('products.name','products.image','products.id',
            'products.image_second','products.description','products.min_order','size_categories.size_id')
        ->get();
```

I thought of trying find_in_set first, but on checking query on telescope, theres nothing there, theres error in this.
I am new to laravel
Please Help
Thank You

Comment: Anuybody there?